# How to change axes linewidth in 3D matplotlib?

Tags: 3d, matplotlib, axes

I am trying to change the line width of the axes in `3D` plots in `matplotlib`. I have tried:

```
"mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 8"

and

"pl.rc("axes", linewidth=8.0)"
```

but none of them worked. I would be grateful for any suggestions.